# JSZip why are downloaded files blank?

Tags: php, jquery, zip, jszip

I am using JSZip.js and FileSaver.js to create a basic download all files function. I am looping through a bunch of folders and files created by the user and then downloading them all as a zip file.

Everything works fine and the folder/file structure is perfect, however all of the files are blank once unzipped. They show as the correct file format and file size as the files on the server but the pages of each PDF are white/empty. How can I fix this?

```
var zip = new JSZip();

<?php foreach ($folder['Subfolder'] as $key => $value):?>
  var folder<?php echo $value['id'];?> = zip.folder("<?php echo $value['name'];?>");

  <?php if (!empty($value['SubfolderFile'])):?>
    <?php foreach ($value['SubfolderFile'] as $key => $file): ?>

      var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/<?php echo $file['subfolder_id'];?>/<?php echo $file['file'];?>");
          folder<?php echo $value['id'];?>.file("<?php echo $file['file'];?>", promise);

    <?php endforeach?>
  <?php endif?>
<?php endforeach?>

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function(content) {
  saveAs(content, "<?php echo $folder['Folder']['name'];?>.zip");
});
```

HTML prints out like this

```
var zip = new JSZip();

var folder92 = zip.folder("PLANNING - Committees");

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/92/(Public Pack)Supplementary Pack 24 Nov 2021  Report Updates Agenda Supplement for Planning Committee.pdf");
folder92.file("(Public Pack)Supplementary Pack 24 Nov 2021  Report Updates Agenda Supplement for Planning Committee.pdf", promise);

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/92/minutes 24th-Nov-2021 11.00 Planning Committee.pdf");
folder92.file("minutes 24th-Nov-2021 11.00 Planning Committee.pdf", promise);

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/92/3. 24 Nov 2021 Committee report.pdf");
folder92.file("3. 24 Nov 2021 Committee report.pdf", promise);

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/92/27 April 2022 Previously Deferred item F420OUT Land at Ford Airfield Ford.pdf");
folder92.file("27 April 2022 Previously Deferred item F420OUT Land at Ford Airfield Ford.pdf", promise);

var folder93 = zip.folder("PLANNING - Approved Drawings Subject to Permission");

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/93/23885 - RG-M-122M - Access and Movement PARAMETER Plan-(1-5000@A1).pdf");
folder93.file("23885 - RG-M-122M - Access and Movement PARAMETER Plan-(1-5000@A1).pdf", promise);

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/93/23885 - RG-M-123L - Land Use and Density PARAMETER Plan-(1-5000@A1).pdf");
folder93.file("23885 - RG-M-123L - Land Use and Density PARAMETER Plan-(1-5000@A1).pdf", promise);

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/93/23885 - RG-M-121N - Green and Blue Infrastructure PARAMETER Plan-(1-5000@A1).pdf");
folder93.file("23885 - RG-M-121N - Green and Blue Infrastructure PARAMETER Plan-(1-5000@A1).pdf", promise);

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/93/23885 - RG-M-152A - Odour Condition Zone-(1-2500@A1).pdf");
folder93.file("23885 - RG-M-152A - Odour Condition Zone-(1-2500@A1).pdf", promise);

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/93/23885 - RG-M-107E - Buildings to be Demolished-1-5000A1.pdf");
folder93.file("23885 - RG-M-107E - Buildings to be Demolished-1-5000A1.pdf", promise);

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/93/23885 Masterplan Document A29.pdf");
folder93.file("23885 Masterplan Document A29.pdf", promise);

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/93/Eastern access drawing.pdf");
folder93.file("Eastern access drawing.pdf", promise);

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/93/Northern access drawing.pdf");
folder93.file("Northern access drawing.pdf", promise);

var promise = $.get("https://www.website.co.uk/img/folders/93/Southern access drawing.pdf");
folder93.file("Southern access drawing.pdf", promise);

var folder95 = zip.folder("LEGAL");

var folder96 = zip.folder("SALE PLAN");

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, "Folder name, here.zip");
});
```

Comment: Your PHP is generating HTML and JS, please take a look at and post that code if you don't see any obvious errors. Also, only look at the View Source, not the Inspect, because you want the literal, not interpreted code

Comment: There are no errors. All files correct size, but visually blank. Question updated with source html.

Comment: The difference when getting the info from the files after downloading is the file direct from the server says Content Creator: Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365, Encoding Software: Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365. And the zipped version of the same file says:  Content Creator: ýý M i c r o s o f t ý   W o r d   f o r   M i c r o s o f t   3 6 5. File size is slightly different: Server: 116,446 bytes (119 KB on disk) and Zipped file: 111,109 bytes (115 KB on disk)

Comment: Is there a way to fix this with jsZip? even when I simplify it and try and download one file from the server it returns a blank file